# SORT_SEQUENCE is wrong in as400 library indexes. Can this cause performance issues?

Tags: db2, collation, iseries

I have 4 AS400s running JDEdwards.

Lately a performance issue occured as described here: [AS400 Performace issue](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60880/sql-statement-slower-on-as400-console-than-from-remote-odbc)

Although i am not an expert in AS400 , i tried to find out the cause. I think it came down to this:

I run the following SQL in all my systems:

```
select sort_sequence,index_schema,count(*) from qsys2.sysindexstat group by sort_sequence,index_schema
```

In 3 of my 4 systems all of them have sort_sequence="BY HEX VALUE"

In my 4 problematic system many indexes have sort_sequence="*LANGIDSHR"

I start to believe that this can cause performance problems as the query optimizer may leave these indexes unused and create temp indexes.

I wish somebody has an idea on where to go on from now and how.

Is there any specific setting that make all the indexes have default sort_sequence?

All my indexes are created massively so this could not happen by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: [Sort Sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/61060/7930)

In short the problm occured from incorrect client odbc setup, making the indexes not *HEX but langauage specific , rendering the index ussage useless fromn server point of view.